# How can I merge multiple maps by the value of a certain key?

Tags: java, dictionary, merge

This is about Java, but for readability's sake, I'm going to write the examples down in JSON.

Say I have a `List` of `Map`s set up like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "foo": 12,
    "bar": 34
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "baz": 56
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "foo": 78
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "bar": 90
}]
```

What I'd like to do is merge maps that have the same `id`. Basically, I want to end up with something like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "foo": 12,
    "bar": 34,
    "baz": 56
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "foo": 78,
    "bar": 90
}]
```

All other questions I found deal with merging maps in unrelated ways, and most are only concerned about two maps, not a variable amount.

This code seems to work, but strikes me as a little verbose:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> toRemove = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();

for (Map<String, Integer> map : list) {
    if (toRemove.contains(map)) {
        continue;
    }
    int id = map.get("id");
    for (Map<String, Integer> otherMap : list) {
        if (map.equals(otherMap)) {
            continue;
        }
        int otherId = otherMap.get("id");
        if (id == otherId) {
            map.putAll(otherMap);
            toRemove.add(otherMap);
        }
    }
}

list.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: in your example there isn't any case in which maps with same id share a key (in this case values should be sumed I guess). It is guaranteed?

Comment: It will be O(n*n) and slow for large data set. One approach will be you can sort list based upon id and do merge till you get the same id..

Comment: @fustaki I can assume they don't share keys apart from `id`, and if they did, it'd be fine to just replace any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would organize the result in a `Map` of Maps

```
Map<Integer, Map<String,Integer>> mapOfMaps = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String,Integer>>();

for(Map<String,Integer> map : list){
    Integer id = map.get("id");
    Map<String,Integer> existingMap = mapOfMaps.get(id);
    if(existingMap == null){
        mapOfMaps.put(id, map);
    }else{
        existingMap.putAll(map);
    }
}
```

As I commented above: this in the case you *don't* need to sum values (apart from `id` maps do not share other keys, or if they do values would be replaced)

Comment: I think this will do nicely - making the result a `Map` is a neat idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just make a `groupMap` that is a new Map, with `id` is the key and element map is value:

```
    List<Map<String, Integer>> toRemove = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();
    Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> groupMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map<String, Integer> m : toRemove) {
        Integer id = m.get("id");
        Map<String, Integer> tmp = groupMap.get(id);
        if (tmp == null) {
            groupMap.put(id, m);
        } else {
            tmp.putAll(m);
        }
    }

    List<Map<String, Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<>(groupMap.values());
```

Then, the `newList` is your result now.

Answer (score 1):

My сrazy solution with streams:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get("id")))
        .values().stream()
        .map(m -> m.stream().<Map<String, Integer>>collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll, Map::putAll))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```